# How is it possible that this select statement works, but this update statement does not in VFP 9?

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, sql-variant

## Overview

I am trying to write a `select` statement in Visual Fox Pro 9 (VFP9) to update a row (and eventually several other records, I wrote a select statement first and it worked great, I got the expected result.

But I'm a little new to VFP9 syntax, *and who wouldn't be in 2013?*  I'm expecting the `UPDATE` which contains my `select` to operate a bit like an `UPDATE INNER JOIN` in actual *non-foxprose SQL*.

### My select statement, it works fine.

```
SELECT temptable3.constate FROM temptable3, prw22001 ;
  WHERE prw22001.empno = temptable3.empno AND temptable3.pssn = prw22001.ssn AND temptable3.empno='5202' AND temptable3.constate <> prw22001.stateid AND prw22001.procyear='2012'
```

### My Update statement (which contains my select statement and doesn't work):

```
UPDATE prw22001 ;
  SET prw22001.stateid = SELECT temptable3.constate FROM temptable3, prw22001 ;
  WHERE prw22001.empno = temptable3.empno AND temptable3.pssn = prw22001.ssn AND temptable3.empno='5202' AND temptable3.constate <> prw22001.stateid AND prw22001.procyear='2012'
```

I get an error that reads Microsoft Visual FoxPro `Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword.` I don't see what it is talking about and a good 4/5ths of my query is my original select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your statement like this:

```
UPDATE prw22001 ;
  SET prw22001.stateid = temptable3.constate ;
  FROM temptable3, prw22001 ;
  WHERE prw22001.empno = temptable3.empno AND temptable3.pssn = prw22001.ssn AND temptable3.empno='5202' AND temptable3.constate <> prw22001.stateid AND prw22001.procyear='2012'
```